# masking out unwanted bits in c

Tags: c

Given the decimal `71744474` in binary it is `0100010001101011101111011010` what I am trying to extract from this decimal is every seven bits starting from the lower bits. Each of the seven bits are to represent a printable ASCII character which can only have 7 bits. In total I am pulling out four characters. The first character is `1011010` which is `Z` in ASCII. The next character is `w` and so on. I am thinking there is a way to mask out the bits I care about some how.

Comment: While dealing with bits. you should take example in hex value. so it will be very much easy to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use bitwise operators:

```
0100010001101011101111011010 & 0000000000000000000001111111 = 1011010
```

To get the second character, do

```
0100010001101011101111011010 & 0000000000000011111110000000
```

and so on..

Comment: But how do you do this in a for loop, and keep the mask moving to expose new bits, and how in the world do you handle masking a different number of bits each time?

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines of this should suffice:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    unsigned int value = 71184592; // Secret key :-)

    for (unsigned int shift = 0; shift < 28; shift += 7)
        printf ("%c", (value >> shift) & 0x7f);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

It uses bit shifting get the specific bits you want into the least significant seven bits of the value, and bit masking to clear out all other bits.

If you run that code, you'll see it can quite happily extract the individual ASCII characters in groups of seven bits each:

```
Pax!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int myN  = 71744474;
int mask = 0x7F7F7F7F; // 7F is 0111 1111, or 7 on bits.

int result = myN & mask;

char myBytes[4];
myBytes[0] = (char)((result        & 0x000000FF);
myBytes[1] = (char)((result >>  8) & 0x000000FF);
myBytes[2] = (char)((result >> 16) & 0x000000FF);
myBytes[3] = (char)((result >> 24) & 0x000000FF);


// Now, examine myBytes[0-3], and I think they'll be what you want.
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite right - the seven bits making up each character are actually packed together while your code assumes 8 bits are used for each and you just zero the top bit of each.

Comment: Ah.... I misunderstood, but paxdiablo explains it better.   I'd fix my answer, but the right one has already been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 71744474;
    a = a&0xFFFFFFF; // 1111111 1111111 1111111 1111111
    while (a>0) {
        char b = a&0x7f; // 1111111
        printf("%c", b);
        a = a>>7;
    }
}
```